# Google Cloud Pub/Sub - Stopped triggering push to endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

It was working fine till last day and suddenly stopped pushing to endpoint. Checked all settings including endpoint URL and found everything remains unchanged. Can you guys suggest possible causes.

Comment: At what time interval are you sending the watch request?

Comment: Just creating the watch request one time and renewing it on 6 days frequency.

Comment: The same thing happened for me as well. And I set the cron Job to send watch request daily. But didn't get any notification after some hours of watch request. So, at last I set it to run the cron Job to send watch request for every two hours. Then it worked. 
Don't know the exact reason behind this but got the solution for now.

Comment: But my frequency is 6 days, and didnt get any alerts regarding this issue

Answer (score 3):

Not receiving a message on a push endpoint could happen for many reasons. The first thing to do would be to go to [Stackdriver](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/) and create a graph for the `subscription/push_request_count` metric. You can break this down by `response_code` to see how many requests Cloud Pub/Sub is sending to your push endpoint and what response codes it is returning. If there are requests being delivered that are returning errors, this graph will show that.

It might also be worth checking the publish side to ensure messages are still being published as expected. You can look at the `topic/send_message_operation_count` metric, which can also be broken down by `response_code`, to make sure the publish requests are all returning success.

You should also check to ensure the subscription still exists using the [Pub/Sub Subscriptions page in the Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/subscriptions). After 30 days of inactivity (including inability to successfully deliver a message to a push endpoint), [subscriptions are potentially deleted](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#other_limits).

If the issue still unsolved after those steps, it is best to contact Google Cloud support with your project ID and subscription name so that things can be investigated for your specific case.